# Posterior mean computation of "Monty Hall Poblem"

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

**Background**

As I understand that the "Monty Hall Problem" is well studied, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem#Direct_calculation) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96826/the-monty-hall-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1), etc. [I am relatively new to probability theory. So, please help me to learn something from you experts here.]

In my understanding so far, summary is that "always switching" has a success rate of 2/3 while "always staying" has a success rate of 1/3.

Just to support my questions, let me denote the Car by C, Monty by M, and the user by X. The door number is a subscript to these defined letters accordingly.

ADD: $C_i$ means Car is behind $i$th door (e.g., $C_1$ means Car is behind door 1); $M_i$ means that Monty opens $i$th door (e.g., $M_3$ means Monty opens door 3), and $X_i$ means that the user selects $i$th door (e.g., $X_1$ means that the user picks door 1).

We start with the assumption that the user selects door 1, that is $X_1$.
Then, according to the above study problems, the posteriors are

\begin{align}
p\left(C_1 \mid M_3, X_1\right) = \frac{1}{3}, \\
p\left(C_2 \mid M_3, X_1\right) = \frac{2}{3}, \\
p\left(C_3 \mid M_3, X_1\right) = 0 \ . \\
\end{align}

My **questions** are as follows:

1. Which door will have the maximum a-posteriori (MAP) solution?

   - It should be door 2, clearly for the above case, isn't it (just a clarification)?
2. What will be the *posterior mean*?

   - I am confused and not sure. Can you please help me?

Thank you.

---

Attempt for the *posterior mean* of the doors:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left( C_i \right) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 i p\left(C_i \mid M_3, X_1\right) \\
&= 1 \underbrace{p\left(C_1 \mid M_3, X_1\right) }_{\frac{1}{3}} + 2 \underbrace{p\left(C_2 \mid M_3, X_1\right) }_{\frac{2}{3}} + 3 \underbrace{p\left(C_3 \mid M_3, X_1\right) }_{0} \\
&= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + 2 \cdot \frac{2}{3} + 0\\
&= \frac{5}{3}
\end{align}

Am I correct?

Comment: What's the difference between $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_3$?

Comment: $M_1$ means that the Monty opens door 1. Likewise for $M_2$ and $M_3$.